# Looking for a real One-Click Checkout for downloadable products

Tags: checkout, downloadable

Question:
I am looking for an extension which offers an OneClick instant checkout for worldpay like PayPal Express for known customers (as mentioned by Adam K below).

More detailed:
I am looking for a real One-Click checkout Extension for different payment methods in a Magento shop.

Here is the status:

- You need to make an account **before** you can enter the shop.
- You need to login **before** you can enter the shop.
- The shop contains only downloadable products.
- There are just two possible payments (PayPal and WorldPay).

It is planed that the customer just have to click on a "pay now" button and is redirected to the payment clearing page. No shopping Card, no original checkout.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal as standard allows Paypal express checkout which cam be placed on the product page and directed straight to paypal for payment processing.  I don't know of a solution with Worldpay.

Sage Pay have a token system so once the customer has checked out once their details will be saved.  You could change the config of the site so when an item is added to the basket you are redirected to the checkout, if this was changed for "onestepcheckout" the all customer details would be saved one one screen/step, including the card details via the Sage Pay token system and all you would need to click would be the place order button.

The final suggestion would be "check with Amazon" as there is a module for tis and buttons can be added to the product page, click to checkout with Amazon, then it has the standard Amazon interface with one confirmation button.

Not ideal solutions to your "one click" but maybe some ideas to explore.